# How to harness javax.security (JAAS) programmatically?

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-7, java-security

I know how to from-login on a javaee web application and to protect URI resource from non-authenticated users. Works.

Now, I thought about using all the Java EE security structure that is already there, simply because I want to avoid to duplicate code and make it worse. I want to avoid to create `@Entity` beans that are already available. Thus I want to secure my EJBs, Backing Bean, CDI beans and URI Resource. All with the same concept. i.e. I need:

- `Role` --> javax.managagement.relation.Role
- `Group` --> java.security.acl.Group???
- `User` --> java.security.Principal

At max, **I want to extend existing implementation and use a more specific implementation**. E.g. `User` --> User with `firstname`, `lastname`, etc.

Is there already an interface `User` in the Java EE security or even an implementation?

Also, if a user is identified with a form-based login, can I check the user's permission also in an EJB (e.g. `@Stateless`)? E.g. with `@RolesAllowed("admin")`. Rephrasing: **Does the login status prevail also for the EJB context and not only in the web context?** (I mean, it's the same container, it should, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is class java.security.Principal (e.g. javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal). It has getName method. You should create custom login module for your application server if you want extend Principal object with new fields.

Comment: Thank for your input. I program Java for a while now, but I could not relate module to a Java concept. How would you do that? Couldn't I simply implement the Principal class and store it as an @Entity? Same with Group (what matches Group in the Java EE security concept?) and Role?

Comment: I depends from  your application server. Can you specify your application server and version (Tomcat, Weblogic, Wildfly, Jboss, etc)?

Comment: I really want to decouple it from any application server. It should run on every Java EE 7 certified app server.

Comment: Login module is separate artifact with different deploy, configuration cycle.  And it is deeply integrated with application server. There is no way to create "general" login module. May be you need some other approach than JAAS (e.g spring security).

Comment: Do you know if the login process is also valid for the EJB context and not limited to the web context, when using a form-based login?

Comment: Yes it is propagate to EJB context too. It is not depended from login type (form-based, basic auth, ...). It is general JAAS feature.